# Which is more efficient in Python: list.index() or dict.get()

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve [a problem on LeetCode.](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) I'm using Python and I made an attempt as follows:

```
def twoSum(self, num, target):
    index0 = 0
    index1 = -1 
    for item in num:
        index0 += 1
        other = target - item
        try:
            index1 = num[index0:].index(other)
            index1 += index0 + 1
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            break
    return index0, index1
```

But I always get the result: `Time Limit Exceeded`
The idea of my code is to check whether `element(other = target - item)` in the list, and I used the `index()` method for this.

The right answer offered on the Internet is as follows:

```
def twoSum(self, num, target):
    length = len(num)
    dic = {}
    for i in xrange(length):
        dic[num[i]] = i
    index0 = -1
    index1 = -1 
    for key in xrange(length):  #not "for key in dic.values():" 
        other = target - num[key]
        index1 = dic.get(other)
        #[1, 2, 3, 4], 4:   2,2 is not the EXPECTED answer.
        if index1 and index1 != key:
            index0 = key + 1
            index1 += 1
            break

    return index0, index1
```

It's OK, but I don't understand what's wrong with my code? Is `list.index()` slower than `dict.get()`?

Comment: Please credit your source for the second snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is `list.index()` slower than `dict.get()`?

In a word, yes: `list.index()` has to scan the list to look for the element, whereas `dict.get()` can do its job in [constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) (i.e. in time that's independent of the size of the dictionary).

Thus the first algorithm's [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is quadratic in the size of the input (written as O(n^2)), whereas the second algorithm's is linear (O(n)).

The following graph illustrates the difference between the two rates of growth:

[image: O(n) vs O(n^2)]

Comment: Isn't it `O(n)` vs. `O(1)`?

Comment: Thanks!<br>Could you please tell me what's the "constant time" exactly means? How can I get its value?

Comment: @glglgl: For the operation, yes. But there's an O(n) loop around that, right?

Comment: @NPE: Oh, right. Thanks for clearing up the misunderstanding.

Comment: @lxw.ucas: Read up on computational complexity. There are a couple of links in my answer. The exact value of the constant does not really matter; what matters is the rate of growth.

Answer (score 1):

A `get` on a dictionary does not do a sequential search, basically it applies a hashing algorithm to the key to find the value in memory.    `index` does a sequential search, so if the item you are looking for is at the start of the list then it could actually be faster!

All things being equal, a dictionary search will be consistent.  The actual time depends on things like the algorithm in use, which in theory can vary between versions of python.  You might also like to consider your test using a `set()` and maybe `collections.OrderedDict`.

You have stumbled across an important reason for having dictionaries.  If you are going to search by position then use a list (or tuple), searching by key then use a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much. After reading your answer, I understand much more about dict in Python.